# IF Statement is not returning a result. Android Studio in Java

Tags: java, if-statement, parsing, integer, double

to summarise this function pulls data from TextView value. It then converts it into a double then is supposed to perform an if statement which identifies which value is higher than the other.

Updated Code:

```
public void getCurrentData();
        TextView user = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.global_text_username);
        String username = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("email");
        String userId = username.substring(0, 5);
        user.setText(username);

        Drawable unreach = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.baseline_remove_circle_24, null);

        TextView user_current_cals = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.home_text_calcode);
        TextView user_current_steps = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.home_text_stepcode);
        TextView user_current_target = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.home_text_targetcode);

        ImageView current_cals = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.home_img_calstatus);
        ImageView current_target = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.home_img_targetstatus);
        ImageView current_steps = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.home_img_stepstatus);
```

The problem happens here. While the code runs without any error, the second if statement is not working.

```
        String ucc = user_current_cals.getText().toString();
        double check_current_cals = Double.parseDouble(ucc);

        String uct = user_current_target.getText().toString();
        double check_current_target = Double.parseDouble(uct);

        String ucs = user_current_steps.getText().toString();
        int check_current_steps = Integer.parseInt(ucs);

        if (check_current_steps < 1000) {
            current_steps.setColorFilter(Color.argb(255, 244, 57, 57));
            current_steps.setImageDrawable(unreach);
        }

        if (check_current_cals < check_current_target) {
            current_cals.setColorFilter(Color.argb(255, 244, 57, 57));
            current_target.setColorFilter(Color.argb(255, 244, 57, 57));
            current_cals.setImageDrawable(unreach);
            current_target.setImageDrawable(unreach);
        }
```

I'm confused to as what's not going right with this statement and any help and pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

I have tried to convert all numbers to Integers and perform the int statement again to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to get the text from the textview.

This is your code:

```
Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(user_current_steps))
```

note, that you use the valueOf `user_current_steps` which is the TextView object. You need to ask it for the actual text:

```
Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(user_current_steps.getText()))
```

And then you can most likely omit the `String.valueOf` part, because that already returns a string:

```
Integer.parseInt(user_current_steps.getText())
```

Comment: Still that won't solve the issue, try getting your double values String text = textView.getText().toString();
double doubleValue = Double.parseDouble(text);

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply however like @Andile has said this doesn't solve my issue.
I have updated the code but my issue still persists with the Doubles. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

ANSWER: Update on my issue. It turned out it was trying to retrieve the values too early which resulted in the if-statement trying to do a (0 < 0) statement.

Before:

```
                public void run () {
                    getUserInfo();
                    getCurrentData();

                }
```

After:

```
                public void run () {
                    getUserInfo();
                }


    public void getUserInfo() {
         //getUserInfo CODE HERE
         getCurrentData();
    }
```

Thanks for the help.